# I Would like to add pause button to my countdown timer in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer

```
$scope.countdown = function () {
    countdownStop = $timeout(function () {
        if ($scope.counter == 0) {
            $scope.stop();
            $scope.completeRound();

        }
        else {
            $scope.counter--;
            $scope.countdown();
        }
    }, 1000);
};

$scope.stop = function () {
    $timeout.cancel(countdownStop);
}
```

here i can able to stop and start but now i would like to add pause button to  my timer when user clicks on pause button how i can i do that i am new to angularjs  i was added one button in my game to pause my game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
$scope.active = true;

$scope.start = function() {
    $scope.active = true;
    $scope.countdown();
};

$scope.countdown = function () {
    countdownStop = $timeout(function () {
        if ($scope.counter == 0) {
            $scope.stop();
            $scope.completeRound();

        }
        else {
            if ($scope.active) {
                $scope.counter--;
                $scope.countdown();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
};

$scope.pause = function() {
    $scope.active = false;
};

$scope.stop = function () {
    $timeout.cancel(countdownStop);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a button call the onPause handler.

```
var pause = false;
$scope.countdown = function () {
   countdownStop = $timeout(function () {
      if ($scope.counter == 0) {
        $scope.stop();
        $scope.completeRound();

      }
      else {
        if(!pause){
        $scope.counter--;
        $scope.countdown();
        }
     }
   }, 1000);
};

$scope.stop = function () {
   $timeout.cancel(countdownStop);
}

$scope.onPause = function(){
pause = !pause;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave jones and i would like to know some more whenever  user click on pause button is it possible to open one box to show all options together like start stop resume and levels  if possible please let me know and i tried with sweet alert and modal but its going to other page how can i do that

Comment: Not sure exactly what your trying to do, won't all controls be visible anyway? If you want to show something when paused you can just put that info in a div and show/hide with ng-show = "pause" that will only appear when pause is truthy.

Comment: yes but i would like to show that div as  pop up and  in that pop up i would like  to show these options for user  start or stop or reply or menu